# An informed leave vs a informed leave

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage, indefinite-article, email

A subordinate sent me an e-mail requesting leave to attend his marriage.

> Kindly take this request into consideration and mark my absence as **a informed leave.**

Can it be "a informed leave"?

My edit:

> Kindly take this request into consideration and mark my absence as **an informed leave.**

"An informed leave" sounds unnatural.

Am I right in using the article "an"?

"kindly request" - should they be used together?

Comment: Note, by the way, that *informed/uniformed leave* is not idiomatic in US English; we would probably express this distinction as *scheduled/unscheduled*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"An informed leave" is correct.

From https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/ . . 
"If the noun is modified by an adjective, the choice between a and an depends on the initial sound of the adjective that immediately follows the article:

```
a broken egg
an unusual problem
a European country (sounds like 'yer-o-pi-an,' i.e. begins with consonant 'y' sound)"
```

Comment: This. I'm not sure if it's considered grammatically correct yet, but "an historic" really grinds my gears, yet it seems to be commonplace in the news.

Comment: @CrazyEyes It's not a matter of "yet", it's a matter of "still".  *An historic* is a weird exceptional leftover that some speakers still observe, but it's been on the decline for some time.

Comment: @snailboat Thanks for clearing that up. I hadn't seen it until I became a teenager, so I thought it was some kind of bizarre new trend.

Answer (score 0):

Jaith answered the a/an part.

RE "kindly": "Kindly" here is being used to mean "please". Some sort of polite word is called for here to make this a request and not a demand. Usually someone would say "Please take this request ..." but "Kindly" is equivalent.

I'm not sure why you specifically ask about combining "kindly" with "request". Why not? They fit together well: a "request" can be made politely, and "kindly" is a way to express a request politely. If someone wrote, "Kindly take this demand into consideration ..." or "Kindly take this ultimatum into consideration ...", that would be odd.